# What to do if there are suspicious entries in nginx error log

Tags: nginx

I'm very very new with server stuff and I have just setup a server with nginx 1.11 and php7.

While I was still configuring my project paths, I often check with the nginx error logs. I noticed there are from suspicious host listed there. For sure I don't own any **7ammart.com**

What should I do?? How do I stop it?
How will I know where it was running from?

Here is the error log:

```
2016/09/11 10:19:19 [error] 3315#3315: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 162.210.196.130, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0", host: "7ammart.com"
2016/09/11 10:19:21 [error] 3315#3315: *2 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php/catalog/product_compare/add/product/1/uenc/aHR0cDovLzdhbW1hcnQuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9ob21lLWZ1cm5pdHVyZS9wb3RhdG8uaHRtbA,,/form_key/uo0p87myURTXoki5/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 162.210.196.130, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php/catalog/product_compare/add/product/1/uenc/aHR0cDovLzdhbW1hcnQuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9ob21lLWZ1cm5pdHVyZS9wb3RhdG8uaHRtbA,,/form_key/uo0p87myURTXoki5/ HTTP/1.0", host: "7ammart.com"
2016/09/11 10:19:23 [error] 3315#3315: *3 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php/wishlist/index/add/product/1/form_key/uo0p87myURTXoki5/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 162.210.196.130, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php/wishlist/index/add/product/1/form_key/uo0p87myURTXoki5/ HTTP/1.0", host: "7ammart.com"
```

I can't believe I have just set this up today and there is already a suspicious activty

Comment: Looks like `7ammart.com` is the hostname of a server running a web spider, which wants to crawl your website. Do you have a `robots.txt` ?

Comment: @PrateekGupta No, it's not mine. Because I haven't pulled my project files yet and I haven't properly pointed my nginx conf yet, too. Those are really from outside. How do I handle this? Im sorry Im a noob, its still my first time to set up a server.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not yours, webcrawlers are there to mine data from web, if you don't want webcrawlers crawling your site, you can specify rules in robots.txt. It's okay, everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: @PrateekGupta So these are web crawlers. Thank you. But where will I put my robots.txt?

Comment: in your html root, the place from where your html files are served, you can find this location, by looking at the `nginx.conf` `Location` variable for the particular host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`7ammart.com` is the `hostname` of a server which is running a `web crawler`. Trying to crawl your website.

Looks like you don't have a `robots.txt`, please add one. There is a guide [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html), which explains how to do that.

You can make rules to deny or allow bots.

Place the file at the root from where your html is served.